# Why does CPU access memory on a word boundary?

Tags: c, assembly, memory, cpu-architecture, memory-alignment

I heard a lot that data should be properly aligned in memory for better access efficiency. CPU access memory on a word boundary.

So in the following scenario, the CPU has to make 2 memory accesses to get a single word.

```
Supposing: 1 word = 4 bytes

("|" stands for word boundary. "o" stands for byte boundary)


|----o----o----o----|----o----o----o----|   (The word boundary in CPU's eye)
           ----o----o----o----              (What I want to read from memory)
```

Why should this happen? **What's the root cause of the CPU can only read at the word boundary?**

If the CPU can only access at the 4-byte word boundary, the address line should only need 30bit, not 32bit width. Cause the last 2bit are always 0 in CPU's eye.

### ADD 1

And even more, if we admit that CPU must read at the word boundary, why can't **the** boundary start at where I want to read? It seems that the boundary is **fixed** in CPU's eye.

### ADD 2

According to *AnT*, it seems that the boundary setting is hardwired and it is hardwired by the memory access hardware. CPU is just innocent as far as this is concerned.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The meaning of "can" (in "...CPU can access...") in this case depends on the hardware platform.

On x86 platform CPU instructions *can* access data aligned on absolutely *any* boundary, not only on "word boundary". The misaligned access might be less efficient than aligned access, but the reasons for that have absolutely nothing to do with CPU. It has everything to do with how the underlying low-level memory access hardware works. It is quite possible that in this case the memory-related hardware will have to make two accesses to the actual memory, but that's something CPU instructions don't know about and don't need to know about. As far as CPU is concerned, it can access any data on any boundary. The rest is implemented transparently to CPU instructions.

On hardware platforms like Sun SPARC, CPU *cannot* access misaligned data (in simple words, your program will crash if you attempt to), which means that if for some reason you need to perform this kind of misaligned access, you'll have to implement it manually and explicitly: split it into two (or more) CPU instructions and thus explicitly perform two (or more) memory accesses.

As for why it is so... well, that's just how modern computer memory hardware works. The data has to be aligned. If it is not aligned, the access either is less efficient or does not work at all.

A very simplified model of modern memory would be a grid of cells (rows and columns), each cell storing a word of data. A programmable robotic arm can put a word into a specific cell and retrieve a word from a specific cell. One at a time. If your data is spread across several cells, you have no other choice but to make several consecutive trips with that robotic arm. On some hardware platforms the task of organizing these consecutive trips is hidden from CPU (meaning that the arm itself knows what to do to assemble the necessary data from several pieces), on other platforms it is visible to the CPU (meaning that it is the CPU who's responsible for organizing these consecutive trips of the arm).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference between CPU and the memory access hardware. It's refreshing.

Comment: It seems that the boundary setting **is** hardwired and it is hardwired **by the memory access hardware**. CPU is just innocent as far as this is concerned.

Comment: @smwikipedia: Well, yes. The word boundaries are actually implemented in the actual RAM chips installed in your computer. Inside these chips the bits of data are organized into words. So, the words are pre-determined, implemented in the actual hardware. The are absolutely fixed for that reason. In order to access data you select a specific word using so called "wordlines" inside the chip and then read or write bits using so called "bitlines".

Comment: Nice answer.  I particularly enjoyed the robotic arm analogy.

Comment: This is a bit oversimplified, IMO.  The CPU includes the L1 cache these days, so unaligned access to it does require extra transistors *in the CPU*.  But yes, it's in the cache-access part of the CPU, which would be simpler if the offsets into a cache line had to be multiples of 4.  More importantly, crossing a cache-line boundary requires two separate accesses, and this is a big complication to supporting unaligned accesses.  (Actual DRAM access happens by reading or writing a whole cache line at a time, in systems with a cache).

Comment: See also [Ulrich Drepper's What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf).  And BTW, modern x86 CPUs spend the transistors to make unaligned accesses have no penalty when they don't cross a cache-line boundary.  (e.g. Intel Nehalem has fast unaligned loads/stores even for 16B SSE vectors, unlike Core2.)  If a loop isn't bottlenecked on load uop throughput (e.g. 2 per cycle), the hardware can soak up the extra loads required for cache-line splits while looping over an array.  See also [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: So @PeterCordes my understanding is, basically it is a restriction arise from how cache memory is made, i.e. you can access memory only across one boundary (cell) in one read or write, much like a grid. Processor have to do a new access operation for reading or writing in another cell in memory.
As a consequence, for the processor to provide a support for unaligned access, complex logic operation and multiple accesses would be needed.

Comment: Also a point to note that if processor doesn't provide support for unaligned access, it can ignore lower 2, 3 bits in the address and if the number of address bits can be reduced for operations, it saves silicon in the processor core as pointed out by @JUSTMYcorrectOPINION below.

Comment: @Sabeeh: You can build a cache that allows reading a chunk from any byte offset into a cache line.  e.g. feed the whole cache line to a barrel shifter or something.  I assume this is what modern x86 CPUs do, since Nehalem and later have full throughput for unaligned loads/stores that don't cross a cache line boundary, even for SSE / AVX vectors.  Yes, it takes extra transistors, but it doesn't have to take two cache accesses.  See [Agner Fog's microarch guide](http://agner.org/optimize/)

Answer (score 8):

It saves silicon in the addressing logic if you can make certain assumptions about the address (like "bottom `n` bits are zero).  Some CPUs (x86 and their work-alikes) will put logic in place to turn misaligned data into multiple fetches, concealing some nasty performance hits from the programmer.  Most CPUs outside of that world will instead raise a hardware error explaining in no uncertain terms that they don't like this.

All the arguments you're going to hear about "efficiency" are bollocks or, more precisely are begging the question.  The real reason is simply that it saves silicon in the processor core if the number of address bits can be reduced for operations.  Any inefficiency that arises from misaligned access (like in the x86 world) are a result of the hardware design decisions, not intrinsic to addressing in general.

Now that being said, for most use cases the hardware design decision makes sense.  If you're accessing data in two-byte words, most common use cases have you access `offset`, then `offset+2`, then `offset+4` and so on.  Being able to increment the address byte-wise while accessing two-byte words is typically (as in 99.44% certainly) not what you want to be doing.  As such it doesn't hurt to require address offsets to align on word boundaries (it's a mild, one-time inconvenience when you design your data structures) but it sure does save on your silicon.

As a historical aside, I worked once on an Interdata Model 70 -- a 16-bit minicomputer.  It required all memory access to be 16-bit aligned.  It also had a very small amount of memory by the time I was working on it by the standards of the time.  (It was a relic even back then.)  The word-alignment was used to double the memory capacity since the wire-wrapped CPU could be easily hacked.  New address decode logic was added that took a 1 in the low bit of the address (previously an alignment error in the making) and used it to switch to a second bank of memory.  Try that without alignment logic!  :)

Answer (score 3):

Because it is more efficient.

In your example, the CPU would have to do two reads: it has to read in the first half, then read in the second half separately, then reassemble them together to do the computation. This is much more complicated and slower than doing the read in one go if the data was properly aligned.

Some processors, like x86, can tolerate misaligned data access (so you would still need all 32 bits) - others like Itanium absolutely cannot handle misaligned data accesses and will complain quite spectacularly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just added something to my post.

Answer (score 3):

Word alignment is not only featured by CPUs

On the hardware level, most RAM-Modules have a given Word size in respect to the amount of bits that can be accessed per read/write cycle.

On a module I had to interface on an embedded device, addressing was implemented through three parameters: The module was organized in four banks which could be selected prior to the RW operation. each of this banks was essentially a large table 32-bit words, wich could be adressed through a row and column index.

In this design, access was only possible *per cell*, so every read operation returned 4 bytes, and every write operation expected 4 bytes.

A memory controller hooked up to this RAM chip could be desigend in two ways: either allowing unrestricted access to the memory chip using several cycles to split/merge unaligned data to/from several cells (with additional logic), or imposing some restrictions on how memory can be accessed with the gain of reduced complexity.

As complexity can impede maintainability and performance, most designers chose the latter [*citation needed*]